# Does Reaper get soul orbs from killing omnics in Uprising?

Tags: overwatch

I was just wondering, since if he did, he would basically stay at full health the entire match.

Comment: Will the downvoter explain? It's a good question.

Comment: It's a question that does not show any research effort, but you didn't need me to tell you that: it's what downvotes mean.

Comment: There is like a single unanswered thread on Blizzard forums with the same question, besides that not much is out there.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I wasn't implying it does - I was just stating what I found out there after a couple quick looks; wasn't arguing against you, I totally agree the question lacks research by the OP.

Comment: @n_palum Alright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite not a very good researched Answer but one, that come up if you play him one round:

Yes he get Soul Orbs but not for every Omnic.
I can't really say if he get only one for the "special" Omnics or normal too but he get some.